# How to apply TagName for all backup files

Tags: oracle, backup, rman

I perform oracle database backup using the following `rman` command:

```
RUN { 
    ALLOCATE CHANNEL disk1 DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT 'C:\Windows\TEMP\%u'; 
    ALLOCATE CHANNEL disk2 DEVICE TYPE DISK FORMAT 'C:\Windows\TEMP\%u'; 
    BACKUP AS COMPRESSED BACKUPSET DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG TAG MyTAG; 
}
```

But unfortunately `MyTag` is applied only for archive logs BS.
The query `list backup;` return 6 rows:

```
BS of archive logs;
BS of data files;
BS of data files;
BS of data spfile;
BS of data controlfile;
BS of archive logs;
```

The query `list backup summary tag 'MyTag';` return only 2 rows

```
BS of archive logs;
BS of archive logs;
```

How to apply `TagName` for all backup files ?

Comment: Try to change `BACKUP AS COMPRESSED BACKUPSET DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG TAG MyTAG;` to `BACKUP AS COMPRESSED BACKUPSET TAG MyTAG DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify the tag for the database backup as well:

```
BACKUP AS COMPRESSED BACKUPSET DATABASE TAG MyTAG PLUS ARCHIVELOG TAG MyTAG;
```

Ok, I tested this, this does not add the specified tag to the controlfile backup. The below creates an additional controlfile backup and adds the specified tag to that as well:

```
BACKUP AS COMPRESSED BACKUPSET DATABASE TAG MyTAG INCLUDE CURRENT CONTROLFILE PLUS ARCHIVELOG TAG MyTAG;
```

Comment: and what about spfile ?

Comment: @isxaker Just add `backup spfile tag MyTAG;`.